# How to create a shared counter in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Is there a way to have a shared counter (shared between workers) in Celery? I am also open to other ideas on how to solve my problem, but would like to stick to Celery. Here is my problem:

I have a task that is dependent on an index passed to it. These tasks could pass or fail, but I need to target a number of passed tasks. If a job fails it should kick off a new job with the next available index.

I can of course do this through a function that tracks the active jobs and initiates the new jobs, but if there was something built in that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `task_failure` celery signal.

```
from celery.signals import task_failure

@task_failure.connect
def fail_task_handler(sender=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    print('a task has failed')
    # start new task or do something else
```

More at http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-failure

Comment: Thanks for reply, would this be executed by the process that created the initial task, or by another worker?

Comment: depends on how you are routing your tasks.